# Which format is better and not time consuming?

Tags: javascript

I am new to web development .. So I am confused time complexity of Java Script , JQuery with Other Programming languages like C , C++.

```
  Format 1:
    var cur_month;    
    cur_month = (new Date().getMonth()) + 1;  // returns 0 to 11
    cur_month = cur_month.toString().length > 1 ? cur_month : '0' + cur_month;

  Format 2:
    var cur_month;            
    cur_month = ((new Date().getMonth()) + 1).toString().length > 1) ? ((new Date().getMonth()) + 1) : '0' + ((new Date().getMonth()) + 1);
```

In format 2 , I am accessing month from 3 new date objects .. But In first format , I am creating only one object and accessing from that .. Which one is better format?

Comment: If both results are same, format 1 is looking better and more readable than format 2.

Comment: I would use the first example as if the code ran at 1 second to midnight on the last day of the month, its possible it would go over to the next month when you create a new date again

Answer (score 1):

Format 1 because you don't create multiple Date object (with slightly different values)

Also I would rewrite the last line.

Adding a string to a number implicitly casts it to a string.

```
var cur_month;    
cur_month = (new Date().getMonth()) + 1;
cur_month = ( cur_month < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + cur_month;
```

Answer (score 0):

definitely the first one, because you're allocating one `Date` object instead of three which uses as much less memory (even though it's *epsilon* in the context of a modern computer) and adds homogeneity (somehow like @WraithNath says, even though the date change problem is not much probable, but still *possible*), and because you make it more readable for the reader of your code (which may be you in 6 months) by not doing lines that are too wide.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the first example as if the code ran at 1 millisecond to midnight on the last day of the month, its possible it would go over to the next month when you create the next date object.

using the first example you have a single date object that wont change during your logic

Comment: well, it's more if it gets executed nanoseconds before month change… I don't think this is really relevant, though not impossible but very not much probable ;-)

Comment: Could you please explain the line 'code ran at 1ms to midnight on the last day of the month '?

Comment: Sure, what I mean is that it is possible for the month to change between instantiating your two date objects. eg, the first date is instantiated at 31st March 23:59:59999, your next date object is instantiated at 1st April 00:00:00001, so when using the month component it would be different to the first date you instantiated. its unlikely to happen often, but it is possible, and its much better to write code so a problem can never occur. (after years of development, and tracking down these one off issues that you thoght would never happen).